# How can I read .txt file from my server [PHP]?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I'm creating a Telegram Bot in PHP.
My aim now is read from a .txt file a integer and put him in a variable.
This text.txt is uploaded in a server. I tryed to do this:

```
$filename = "http://<MY HOST NAME>/test_bot/file/text.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r+");
$send = fgets($fp);
fclose($fp);

echo $send;
```

But when I try to open my index.php, nothing comes out written.
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There should be a line in your error log along the lines of *HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections...*. Looking at your logs will help your diagnose issues like this a lot faster.

Comment: Also if I write r instead of r+, I can't see the value of $send

Comment: have you check the text.text is accessible like "chmod -777" kind of things?

Comment: What happens if you open that given link in your browser directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are opening from a remote host you can't open for read/write, just read. Try this instead:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
```

If you are trying to open a file on the same server as the PHP script then do not use the "http://..." path but instead the local file path and then you can open it for read/write. In the case of your script it does not appear you need write access so "r" should be sufficient.

To access without http just use the path to the file:

```
$filename = '/path/to/file/text.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, "r+");
```

Or if you want a relative path from the script itself I prefer:

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../some/relative/path/text.txt';
```

Comment: Yes i'm trying to open a file on the same server as the PHP script then I've to write only "/file/text.txt"?

Comment: If you are on the same server then avoid using http to access the file and instead use the direct file path. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've write tihs:
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../some/relative/path/text.txt';
and it works fine!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Mark as the accepted answer when you are able.

Comment: It seems that I can't write on my files. Do you thing that the problem is my hosting provider?

Comment: The problem is likely the file permissions on your server. What process created the file in the first place? If it was created by one of your PHP scripts then you should still be able to write to it, but if it was uploaded or created another way the user ownership is probably wrong. It will need to be group writable (`chmod g+w filename.txt`) or world writeable (not usually recommended: `chmod o+w`)